# Why google-oauth API requires redirect-url?

Tags: rest, http, security, authorization, google-oauth

I'm trying to set up an authorization flow with google-oauth2 API.
The task is to authorize users with google accounts in my web-application which consists of frontend and backend parts.

The flow according to the documentation consists of 2 steps:
1) obtaining an auth code
2) exchanging  an auth code for a token

In my flow, FE client obtains an auth code from google and submits it to BE, which then exchanges it for a token, so no redirect URL (or sometimes called callback URL) is used.

I do not understand why google API requires me to provide `redirect_uri` for the second step? Since this step is performed by a server, not a browser, I don't see any sense in this piece of info. The server just calls the `POST /oauth2/v4/token` google endpoint and receives token in response.

see step 4 at https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenIDConnect

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/44214/what-is-the-purpose-of-oauth-2-0-redirect-uri-checking), it's to guard against stealing the `access_token`. If a service doesn't check the initial `redirect_uri`, the authorization code is sent to the hacker's `redirect_uri`, which can then exchange it for an `access_token`, i.e. illegal access to the user's account. To actually get the `access_token`, the `redirect_uri` is specified again and this time must be checked by the server against the ones that are registered for that application. At that point, the hacker is foiled as the fake `redirect_uri` doesn't match any of the legal ones. Apparently some servers don't check the `redirect_uri` during the authorization stage and sending the `redirect_uri` again when requesting the `access_token` is meant to provide a final safey check.